# Convert working UK Phone Number JS RegExp to HTML Pattern RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to get this RegExp of a UK phone number to work in an HTML pattern attribute, I can do basic RegExp, but this is beyond me.

So the pattern is (from; [Regular expression for UK based and only numeric phone number in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518035/regular-expression-for-uk-based-and-only-numeric-phone-number-in-cakephp))

```
^(?:(?:\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?(?:\(?0\)?[\s-]?)?)|(?:\(?0))(?:(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5})|(?:\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3}))|(?:\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4})|(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}))(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?|\#)\d{3,4})?$
```

and works fine in the console and returns the expected results. The pattern in the INPUT attribute matches exactly to the above so it's not a escaping issue so far.

The console gives me the error `Invalid escape` with the above. Removing the escaped characters, gives me `Invalid group`

Reading further on the issue ([invalid escape in pattern HTML/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409872/invalid-escape-in-pattern-html-javascript)), I tried escaping `]` and the console tells me `Invalid character class`

```css
input:valid { border-color: green; }
input:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
RegExp original (Invalid escape);<br/>
<input type="tel" name="mobile" autocomplete="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" pattern="^(?:(?:\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?(?:\(?0\)?[\s-]?)?)|(?:\(?0))(?:(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5})|(?:\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3}))|(?:\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4})|(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}))(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?|\#)\d{3,4})?$" required="required">
<br/><br/><br/>
RegExp with escaped ] (Invalid character class):<br/>
<input type="tel" name="mobile" autocomplete="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" pattern="^(?:(?:\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-\]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-\]?(?:\(?0\)?[\s-\]?)?)|(?:\(?0))(?:(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-\]?\d{4,5})|(?:\d{4}\)?[\s-\]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-\]?\d{3}))|(?:\d{3}\)?[\s-\]?\d{3}[\s-\]?\d{3,4})|(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-\]?\d{4}[\s-\]?\d{4}))(?:[\s-\]?(?:x|ext\.?|\#)\d{3,4})?$" required="required">
<br/><br/><br/>
RegExp with no escaped characters (Invalid group):<br/>
<input type="tel" name="mobile" autocomplete="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" pattern="^(?:(?:(?(?:0(?:0|11))?[s-]?(?|+)44)?[s-]?(?:(?0)?[s-]?)?)|(?:(?0))(?:(?:d{5})?[s-]?d{4,5})|(?:d{4})?[s-]?(?:d{5}|d{3}[s-]?d{3}))|(?:d{3})?[s-]?d{3}[s-]?d{3,4})|(?:d{2})?[s-]?d{4}[s-]?d{4}))(?:[s-]?(?:x|ext.?|#)d{3,4})?$" required="required">
<br/><br/><br/>
<button onclick="alert(/^(?:(?:\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?(?:\(?0\)?[\s-]?)?)|(?:\(?0))(?:(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5})|(?:\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3}))|(?:\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4})|(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}))(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?|\#)\d{3,4})?$/.test('07904 333 278'))">Test JS</button>
```

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895209/html-input-pattern-not-working/39899720#39899720). All you need to do is to remove ``\`` in front of `#` since it is not one of the following chars: `^`, `$`, ``\``, `.`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `|`.

Comment: You are a legend, thank you very much.

Comment: Just follow a simple rule: do not escape what does not need to be escaped in a regex pattern, and try to write patterns with as few escapes as possible.