# Javascript - how to exclude certain characters from a given regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex `/^\S.*$/` that matches almost any charset including Chinese, Arabic, Cyrillic, etc. characters (which is important for my use case). The problem with this regex is it also matches special characters. I  don't need other special characters except `,`, `.`, `'`, and `-`. How should I modify my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for `\p{L}` which "matches any kind of letter from any language" according to Regex101.com

Comment: Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891129/regular-expression-pl-and-pn

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but why does `/\p{L}/.test("مجيد الألم ");` return false in Node?

Comment: No need to apologize! Looks like `\p` expressions probably just aren't supported in the default JS environment. This library supports it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/xregexp.html

MY apologies, I assumed it would work after testing it in regex101

Comment: Looks like someone extracted the `\p` specific functionality here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-regex-pl

And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210296/1042144), JS will support it starting in ECMAScript 2018