# Regex find alphanumeric Danish characters delimited with @ and whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find strings delimited with **`@`** and whitespace. It contains Danish alphabet or 4 digits number.

---

In the text below, I want to match all of the characters between **`@`** and whitespace.

> Lorem @**ipsum** dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minus rem fugit @**reprehenderit**  @**velit** voluptate voluptas ipsa quos deleniti beatae soluta, libero nisi @**necessitatibus** eius. @**4000** Numquam, dolorum. Nihil, @**dolorem** animi @**vokalforråd**.

---

I  want to match none of the  words between **`@`** and whitespace in this text.

> Lorem@ipsum.com dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt natus officiis tenetur repellat doloremque @ipsum-co quasi dicta explicabo eius, esse non eum Lorem@ipsum nostrum rerum. Vitae maiores velit esse porro placeat eveniet.

## Info

Danish alphabet consists of English alphabet + `æ`,`ø`, and `å`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet

Comment: How about split loop trim add

Comment: `I want to escape all of the strings in this text` -- that request is very ambiguous. What does "escape" mean to you in this context, and what are "all the strings"? Are you talking about all the matches again between `@` and whitespace?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts. Yes. Updated the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382460/handling-danish-special-characters

Comment: @meistermuh PHP != JavaScript. The regexes used in those answers are not valid in JavaScript.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh I see, sorry, you're right. Natively the "old" JavaScript doesn't. The "new" one does. The old one would need help like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210296/7424979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be happy to update my answer based on clarifications, but given your current criteria, `@vokalforråd.` should *not* be matched because it ends with `.` instead of whitespace.

```js
const tests = ['Lorem @ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque minus rem fugit @reprehenderit  @velit voluptate voluptas ipsa quos deleniti beatae soluta, libero nisi @necessitatibus eius. @4000 Numquam, dolorum. Nihil, @dolorem animi @vokalforråd.', 'Lorem@ipsum.com dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt natus officiis tenetur repellat doloremque @ipsum-co quasi dicta explicabo eius, esse non eum Lorem@ipsum nostrum rerum. Vitae maiores velit esse porro placeat eveniet.']
const pattern = /(?:^|\s)@[\da-zæøå]+(?=\s)/gi

tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log(test.match(pattern))
})
```

You'll need to trim the leading whitespace, if any, from each of the matches with this particular pattern. You can do that with [`string.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to match `Lorem@ipsum`. I only want to match a word if there is a space before `@` and a space after of it (word).